# How to connect 5-15P plug into 6-20R receptacle?

Tags: code-compliance, cord-and-plug, 120-240v

I have a computer power supply (PSU), input voltage is 120-240V, I assume I can safely plug it into a 240V outlet. I have one those outlets in my garage, problem is that it is 6-20R type receptable and the PSU plug is 5-15P and does not fit. What should I do while being code-compliant? Change the 6-20R receptacle to a 5-15R and label it with 220V? Or, is there something like a 6-20R to 5-15R adapter that could be used? Please advise.

Comment: Make sure your computer power supply is auto switching (120/240V) if not there should be a slider switch on it for the input voltage change (no slider switch with those input voltage specs means it is auto-switching) . Most new units are auto switching - but just in case .. you should verify it.

Comment: Understood. I have 4, 2 are auto-switching, 2 are manual. Thanks

Comment: Hey! On the same topic. It is easy to find surge protectors strips for connecting multiple appliances on 120V. I have struggled to find the same for 240V. Am I losing surge protection if I connect directly to the 240V without one? Are 240V surge protectors available, where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your computer power supply accepts its power through a C13 socket, you could use a pigtail to make the connection.

Example: [6-20P to C13 Power Cords](https://www.pduwhips.com/products/2121-computer-power-cords.aspx)

Cables like this are commonly used in data centers to get 240V tolerant equipment attached to the rack PDU.